# how to create dummy variables in Pandas when columns can have mixed types?

Tags: python, pandas

How to create dummy variables in Pandas (Python 2.7) has been asked many times, but I dont know a **robust and fast** solution yet. Consider this dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,-1,np.nan, 'rh']})
df
Out[9]: 
     A
0    1
1    2
2   -1
3  NaN
4   rh
```

yes, it has mixed types. Happens all the time with big datasets (I have **millions** of rows)

I need to create dummy variables that are 1 if a condition is true, and zero otherwise. I am assuming that if Pandas cannot perform the logical comparison (say comparing whether a string is larger than some real number), I would get a zero. Look at this instead:

```
df['dummy2']=(df.A > 0).astype(int)

df['dummy1']=np.where(df.A>0,1,0)

df
Out[12]: 
     A  dummy2  dummy1
0    1       1       1
1    2       1       1
2   -1       0       0
3  NaN       0       0
4   rh       1       1
```

Clearly this is problematic. What is happening here? How can I prevent these false flags?

Many thanks!

Comment: How about `pd.to_numeric(df.A, errors='coerce').notnull() & (df.A > 0)` ?

Comment: thanks. but what is the logic here? why would `'rh' > 0` be evaluated as True?

Comment: @Noobie http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways you could do

```
In [37]: pd.to_numeric(df.A, errors='coerce').notnull() & (df.A > 0)
Out[37]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
Name: A, dtype: bool

In [38]: df.A.apply(np.isreal) & (df.A > 0)
Out[38]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

Third could perhaps be slow

```
In [39]: df.A.str.isnumeric().isnull() & (df.A > 0)
Out[39]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Err ... `df.A > 0` will fail in Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: @JohnGalt pointed out in the comments a better way would be to use `pd.to_numeric` with `errors='coerce'`:

```
# Your condition here, instead of `> 0`, using the fact that NaN > 0 == false
[18]: df['dummy1'] = (pd.to_numeric(df.A, errors='coerce').notnull() > 0).astype('int')
[19]: df
Out[19]:
     A  dummy1
0    1       1
1    2       1
2   -1       0
3  NaN       0
4   rh       0
```

---

<s>The best way</s> One general way to create such dummy variables will be along these lines:

```
def foo(a):
    try:
        tmp = int(a)
        return 1 if tmp > 0 else 0 # Your condition here.
    except:
        return 0

[12]: df.A.map(foo)
Out[12]:
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    0
4    0
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

---

You are doing the operations in Python 2.7, where [comparisons between `str` and `int` are (unfortunately) allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int). The operations fail on Python 3:

```
 [5]: df.A > 0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-890e73655a37> in <module>()
----> 1 df.A > 0

/home/utkarshu/miniconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py in wrapper(self, other, axis)
    724                 other = np.asarray(other)
    725
--> 726             res = na_op(values, other)
    727             if isscalar(res):
    728                 raise TypeError('Could not compare %s type with Series'

/home/utkarshu/miniconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py in na_op(x, y)
    646                     result = lib.vec_compare(x, y, op)
    647             else:
--> 648                 result = lib.scalar_compare(x, y, op)
    649         else:
    650

pandas/lib.pyx in pandas.lib.scalar_compare (pandas/lib.c:14186)()

TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
```